# while reversing the singly linked list using recursion why is the space complexity o(1) when we are using the stack space inside the memory

Tags: python, linked-list

while reversing the singly linked list using recursion why is the space complexity o(1) when we are using the stack space inside the memory

```
def reverse(self,head):
        if(head==None or head.next==None):
            return head
        res=self.reverse(head.next)
        head.next.next=head
        head.next=None
        return res
```

Answer (score 0):

The *big O complexity* is not a very precise measure neither for time nor for space. It just says how an algorithm will behave when the number of the input elements grows.

You are right on one point, the stack usage will be linear (so O(n)), **but that part is independant of the size of an element**. Furthermore in Python, even if the stack uses memory it is handled specially, and the maximum recursion depth is controlled by `sys.getrecursionlimit` and `sys.setrecursionlimit` and it uses a dedicated memory array, in the sense that it is reserved whether you use it or not. For that reason the stack usage is generally not considered when we speak of space complexity.